# Problem in realizing the World Series problem

Tags: information-theory

I have a problem in realizing the World Series solution. The World Series is a seven-game series that terminates as soon as either team wins four games. Let X be the random variable that represents the outcome of a World Series between teams A & B; Possible values of X are AAAA, BABABAB and BBBAAA. Let Y be the number of games played, which ranges from 4 to 7. Now we want H(X) and Y(X|Y) . ( H(X) is the entropy of X).

My problem is in the first part of solution. Can anyone explain this part for me:

[image: solution]

Comment: possible source:  the last page of https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~muysal/self_exercise_questions_ch2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compute the entropy of $X$, you must enumerate its possible outcomes and the corresponding probabilities. Note that the possible $X$ events correspond to either $Y=4,5,6,$ or $7$. The enumeration goes as follows:

- For $Y=4$, either $X=AAAA$ or $BBBB$. Thats two events of probability $(1/2)^4$ (assuming that both teams have equal probability of winning a game)
- Consider $Y=5$. Either $A$ won the series or $B$. If $A$ won the series, $A$ must have won the last (fifth) game and $3$ out of the $4$ first games, hence there are $4 \choose 3$ possible $X$ events corresponding to $A$ winning the series in $Y=5$ games. The same number of events also holds for the case of $B$ winning the series in $Y=5$ games. Therefore, for this case there are a total of $2 {4 \choose 3}$ events, each with a probability $(1/2)^5$
- I will leave the enumeration of $X$ for $Y=6,7$ to you...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question about this problem. Here in the solution it is said that H(Y|X)=0 . Why? And why H(X|Y) is not equal to 0 like H(Y|X)?

Comment: @helen The condition $H(A|B)=0$ holds if and only if the random variable $A$ is perfectly known given the value of the random variable $B$.

Comment: So Y is perfectly known when the value of X is given ( H(Y|X)=0 ), but we cannot be sure about the value of X even when Y is given.

Comment: @helen Yes, isn't that obvious? You may want to explicitly compute $H(Y|X)$ (by computing the corresponding conditional probabilities) to convince yourself that it is zero.